# Remove symbol from Desktop thing in KDE Plasma

Tags: plasma

I accidentally drag&dropped something onto some thing in KDE Plasma and now I got a libre office icon that I don't want there. See screenshot.

Unfortunately, being able to add it easily doesn't mean it's easy to remove. How do I get rid of that symbol?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the image below:

- Click on the ☰ symbol in the top-right corner and select *Unlock Widgets*. (This step is not needed if you haven't locked widgets in the first place.)
- Then click on the ☰ symbol in the bottom-right corner. Hover your mouse pointer over the widget you wish to remove and click on the red "Close" button.

[image]